# Storing an image in sql server 2008 using image location in string

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have an image with location

```
string Imageloc = C:\\Documents and Settings\\All Users\\Documents\\My Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Sunset.jpg
```

and i use the following query to insert the image in DB

```
"UPDATE Employee SET Image = '(SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'" + Imageloc + "', SINGLE_BLOB) as Image)' WHERE EmployeeID = (SELECT MAX(EmployeeID) FROM Employee";
```

I get the following exception

```
Incorrect syntax near '\\'.\r\nIncorrect syntax near 'Employee'
```

Please tell me how to solve it... I dont know how to replace `'\\'` from the string to `'\'`

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean:

```
"UPDATE Employee SET Image = 
  '(SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'" + Imageloc + "', SINGLE_BLOB) as Image)' 
    WHERE EmployeeID = (SELECT MAX(EmployeeID) FROM Employee)";
                                                            ^
```

Comment: yes... Now it says " cannot convert implicitly from varchar to varbinary(max)"

Comment: yes... Now it says " cannot convert implicitly from varchar to varbinary(max)"